# Unable to understand correlation coefficient / auto correlation

Tags: statistics, covariance, correlation

Suppose I have a vector say:

[5 5 5 5 4 5]

then common sense says that there is a very high auto-correlation for the vector because it is more or less the same values.
But when I try to calculate the auto-correlation coefficient, I'm getting a very low value(<0.3) for all lags. What does this mean? shouldn't it be higher because the series is very similar? 
Am I missing something?
does correlatiom mean not similarity but similarity in rate(Rate of change)?

Comment: You would have the same autocorrelation with $(1,1,1,1,-5,1)$ since location and scale are irrelevant to correlation.  For a lag of $1$ that is going be small and negative as you are in effect looking at the pairs $(1,1), (1,1), (1,1), (1,-5), (-5,1)$ where the last two more than offset the first three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar situation arises when you fit a regression line to perfectly horizontal data — you get a “linear” relationship that is nearly perfect but also completely uninformative.

Correlation measures how *changes* in X about its mean are related to *changes* in Y about its mean. In the case where one of the variables is (or is almost) constant, then there isn’t much variation left to attribute to the other variable: